# Reactjs Object.keys() in ComponentDidMount wont update local State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React newbie here. I have a problem trying to obtain an array of keys of a redux state object (this.props.message) in my componentDidMount function. I want to have these messages loaded so that my component can render the keys in a list accordingly. 
   The problem is, in my componentDidMount when I console.log(this.props.message) I get the right object logged but my Object.keys(this.props.message) returns an empty array. To test, I added a clickHandler to one of my buttons to see if it was a life cycle problem using the same snippet of code. Everything works when I click the button and my local state is changed correctly to the appropriate array.
   Can anyone shine some light on what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import _ from 'underscore';
import Message from '../components/Message'

class Inbox extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      inboxNames:false
    }
  }

componentDidMount(){
  console.log('in componentDidMount', this.props.message)
  var newArray = Object.keys(this.props.message)
  this.setState({inboxNames:newArray})
}

  clickHandler(){
  var newArray = Object.keys(this.props.message);
  this.setState({inboxNames:newArray})
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.state.inboxNames)
    return(
      <div className='inboxContainer'>
          <div className='inbox'>
          </div>
        <div className='userProfile'>
          <button onClick={() => this.clickHandler()}>Add Game</button>
          <button>Available for Hosting</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    position: state.rootReducer.position,
    search:state.rootReducer.search,
    markers:state.rootReducer.markers,
    markerClicked:state.rootReducer.markerClicked,
    user:state.rootReducer.user,
    message:state.rootReducer.messages
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  success: () => dispatch(push('/')),
  locationFunction: (position) => dispatch({type:"LOCATION", lat:position.coords.latitude, long:position.coords.longitude}),
  defineUser: (user) => dispatch({type:'USER', user:user})
});

Inbox = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Inbox);

export default Inbox;
```

The following is the what is logged by the console.log in the componentDidMount function.

```js
in componentDidMount
{}
heytherefriend@gmail.com:
{key: "-Ksj1j2aKJyWD5q28Bhs", chat: Array(1)}
peter@gmail.com:
{key: "-KtI338W3l03wIYaOmFW", chat: Array(1)}
thegreekjester@gmail.com:
{key: "-KsesFczZbIO2wJxLKh5", chat: Array(1)}
__proto__:Object
```

Comment: Can you add what the structure of the message looks like, perhaps what your `console.log()` prints out

Comment: im not too sure how to input a log statement neatly in comments, if you know let me know so I can make it look a bit more readable

Comment: Just update your original post to include that

Comment: Updated! Hopefully thats more readable.

Comment: is it a firebase project?

Comment: It is a firebase project.